# How to run all `Test runner` tests from package.json script?

Tags: node.js, testing, npm

I have tests written with the new [Test runner](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/test.html) in a `tests` folder. The files are named `foo.test.mjs`, `bar.test.mjs`.

An example SUD `./lib/foo.mjs` is:

```
export class Foo {
    name = 'Foo'
}
```

An example test `./tests/foo.test.mjs` is:

```
import {describe, it} from 'node:test'
import {equal} from 'node:assert'
import {Foo} from '../lib/foo.mjs'

describe('Foo', () => {
    it('create', () => {
        const foo = new Foo()
        equal(foo.name, 'Foo', 'Name must match')
    })
})
```

I can run a single test with `npm test` if I set a single test file as:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./tests/foo.test.mjs"
  }
}
```

How to run all tests `xxx.test.mjs` in the 'tests' folder with `npm test`?

Unfortunately, `"test": "node ./tests/*.test.mjs"` gives: `Error: Cannot find module 'foo\tests\*.test.mjs'`

Comment: Of course: `"test": "node --test ./tests"`. But who reads the documentation? Anyway, it may be helpful for other huga-buga programmers. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/test.html#running-tests-from-the-command-line